# Thymeleaf doesn't print list of objects (Spring JPA)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have 5 different object of class Tour with some fields.I want that my main page shows this object with their fields.
I wrote conrtoller:

```
        @Controller
        public class MainController {
            @Autowired
            private TourRepository tourRepository;
        
            @GetMapping("/")
            public String mainPage(Model model) {    
               
            List<Tour> tourList=tourRepository.findAll();    
            model.addAttribute("tours",tourList);
        
            return "home/main";
            }    

            @RequestMapping("/main")
            public String main() {
       
            return "redirect:/";}
    }
```

And Repository

```
public interface TourRepository extends JpaRepository<Tour,Integer> {  
}
```

application.properties:

```
# hibernate configurations
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


# thumeleaf configurations
spring.thymeleaf.mode= HTML
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Now I'm trying to pass variable values to the page with Thymeleaf,

```
<div>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each ="tour : ${tours}">
                <td th:utext="${tour.title}">...</td>
                <td th:utext="${tour.price}">...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

but I get five identical duplicates of first record in db.
How can I change controller\view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My primary key named "code" in entity tout in db. Annotation `@Id` didn't a column with a different name as a primary key. I explicitly added:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "code")
private int id;
```